# How to select rows from a table while using CTE and possibly a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to select the rows for MEDs (type) and the related child rows for ORAL (type) where each MED type has multiple ORAL types from the following table.

| ID | PARENT_ID | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | MED |
| 2 | 1 | ORAL |
| 3 | NULL | MED |
| 4 | 3 | ORAL |
| 5 | 3 | IV |
| 6 | NULL | MED |
| 7 | 6 | ORAL |
| 8 | NULL | MED |
| 9 | 8 | ORAL |
| 12 | NULL | MED |
| 13 | 12 | ORAL |
| 14 | 12 | IV |
| 15 | 12 | ORAL |

This should return rows with ID 12, 13, and 15. I've tried the following using a CTE to my multiple counts of ORAL rows. Then tried joining that to pull the three rows I need, but it doesn't return the way I think it should. It's returning the IDs but only in two rows.

```
WITH COUNT_CTE (ID, CNT)
AS
(
    SELECT A.ID, COUNT(A.ID) AS CNT
    FROM Table1 A
    JOIN Table1 B
    ON A.ID = B.PARENT_ID 
    WHERE A.TYPE = 'MED' and B.TYPE = 'ORAL'
    GROUP BY A.ID
)

SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM Table1 A
JOIN Table1 B
ON A.ID = B.ID
JOIN COUNT_CTE C
ON A.ID = C.ID
WHERE A.TYPE = 'MED' AND B.TYPE = 'ORAL' AND C.CNT > 1
```

This returned:

| ID | PARENT_ID | TYPE | ID | PARENT_ID | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | NULL | MED | 13 | 12 | ORAL |
| 12 | NULL | MED | 15 | 12 | ORAL |

I'm not sure if a CTE is even needed or if the group by could be done inside a subquery. Either way I'm not sure how to separate the children into their own rows to look like the below correct return.

The return should be:

| ID | PARENT_ID | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | NULL | MED |
| 13 | 12 | ORAL |
| 15 | 12 | ORAL |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in three steps. Count the children, like you are. Then join on only rows with multiple children and child or parent rows.

```
-- Get a count of how many ORAL rows each MED parent has.
with child_count as (
  SELECT A.id, COUNT(A.ID) AS CNT
  FROM Table1 A
  JOIN Table1 B
  ON A.ID = B.PARENT_ID 
  WHERE A.TYPE = 'MED' and B.TYPE = 'ORAL'
  GROUP BY A.ID
)
select table1.*
from child_count cc
join table1
  -- Filter for only rows with a parent with more than one child.
  on cc.cnt > 1
  -- And only child ORAL rows, or parent rows.
  and (
    (cc.id = table1.parent_id and table1.type = 'ORAL')
    or cc.id = table1.id
  )
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/PwWo6TYv).

Answer (score 1):

Many solutions, here's one using using INTERSECT within a CTE.

```
with target_meds as (
  select id
  from my_table
  where type = 'MED'
  intersect
  select parent_id
  from my_table
  where type = 'ORAL'
  group by 1
  having count(id) > 1
 )
select m.*
from my_table m
join target_meds t
  on coalesce(m.parent_id, m.id) = t.id
where m.type in ('MED', 'ORAL');
```

| id | parent_id | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | null | MED |
| 13 | 12 | ORAL |
| 15 | 12 | ORAL |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qchA6JdHE1q9XvEtnsTyHs/0)